Can a Fairy Armorer Artificer Fly with Heavy Arcane Armor?
With regards to Fairy flight, Monsters of the Multiverse states the following on Page 14:

Flight. Because of your wings, you have a flying speed equal to your
walking speed. You can't use this flying speed if you're wearing
medium or heavy armor.

However, with regards to Armorer Artificers, Tasha's Cauldron of Everything states the following on Page 15 with regards to Arcane Armor:

Your metallurgical pursuits have led to you making armor a conduit for
your magic. As an action, you can turn a suit of armor you are wearing
into Arcane Armor, provided you have smith's tools in hand. You gain
the following benefits while wearing this armor: If the armor normally
has a Strength requirement, the arcane armor lacks this requirement
for you. (etc)

My question is does this result in Fairy Armorer Artificers being able to fly while wearing Heavy Arcane Armor?

No, as Arcane medium or heavy armor is still medium or heavy armor
The Arcane Armor feature only says this about how the normal armor attributes of your armor are modified:

If the armor normally has a Strength requirement, the arcane armor lacks this requirement for you.

It does does not say that the armor ceases to be light, medium, or heavy armor. It does not change the armor's weight. It does not change the armor's AC. As there are no hidden rules, if there is no rule that says is not medium or heavy armor any more, then it still is medium or heavy.
Note that you also gain proficiency in heavy armor at the same level as part of your "Tools of the Trade" feature. If your armor ceased to count as heavy armor once turned Arcane, this would not be needed, as there then would not be any heavy armor penalties that this proficiency frees you from.
Since your Faerie cannot fly while wearing such armor, you cannot fly with it.
You can (as always) discuss with your DM if they think it is no problem to allow you the better AC of heavier armor while flying and house rule this for you differently.

P.S. The page "Updates in the Player's Handbook (2024)" on D&D Beyond explains under "Using this Book with Older Books":

Any subclass, spell, or feat from Xanathar’s Guide to Everything or Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything that appears in this book replaces the version that appears in the Everything book.

but as Artificer and Fairy are not a class or species in the 2024 PHB, they are not being replaced by the new rules, and their specific features function just as they did under the 2014 rules*, so this should apply to either rule set.
(* apart from the spells that have been changed in the 2024 rules, but the features under discussion here are not spells.)

A potential in universe reason for this could be that "Light armour provides holes, or other accommodations, for wings hence it's reduced defensive capabilities. Medium and heavy armour provide no such accommodations, so even though you've made it lighter (I assume this is part of what it's doing as the strength requirement is removed) it still doesn't have the necessary accommodations for wings."

@SamDean I don't think it becomes lighter so much as it becomes a self-supporting suit of magic power armour.

I think both of those are correct. Arcane Armor turns it into Iron Man style powered armor, which removes the strength requirement, and also med/heavy armor is restrictive in ways that make wings unusable no matter how many pounds the armor actually weighs.
